Elasticsearch - getting documents without nested object that not matching query
Is it possible to retrieve documents from ES, but in nested objects without records which not matching query?
My mappings:
"mappings": {
  "properties": {
    "prdId": {
      "type": "long"
    },
    "prdDeleted": {
      "type": "boolean"
    },
    "prdEAN": {
      "type": "keyword",
      "index": false
    },
    "prdCat": {
      "type": "nested",
      "properties": {
        "catalogId": {
          "type": "long"
        },
        "price": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "priceGross": {
          "type": "double"
        },
        "vat": {
          "type": "float"
        },
        "hasHistory": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      }
    },
  }
}

I have list of products, and nested field prdCat where I store a list of catalogs in which a given product is located, and properties from that catalog.
If i search by nested field prdCat to get product which are in a given catalog (example catalogId = 1) i retrieve products correctly, but in nested field I have all objects, not just one where catalogId = 1
In general, I would like to reduce the size of data in response from ES, but currently I get a lot of data in the nested field that is unnecessary, one product can have several dozen catalogs.
I checked the "inner_hits" option, it works, but it adds an additional field to the returned data, which contains nested objects that match the query, "_source" field still contains whole nested objects and the finally data size is even bigger than before.
Does anyone have any ideas?
Thanks in advance.
